# How to remove spaces between table cells

Tags: javascript, html

As you can see under 2nd row of my table between two cells there is a space which I want to remove but I am not sure how to achieve that.

Any help or suggestion will appreciated.Thanks

```js
var str1 = "78896541230";
str1 = str1.replace(/.(?=.{4})/g, 'x');
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = str1;
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" class="formtable">
 
    <caption>Just for fun</caption>
    <tr>
      <td>The following will contain masked input number </td>
      <td id="output"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> If it is not masked number, then something is wrong.</td>
    </tr>
  
</table>
```

Comment: Tags are in your markup. You're asking about _elements_, specifically table cells.

Comment: It helps visualize table structure if you put borders on your cells, even temporarily. Once you do that the issue becomes apparent. https://jsfiddle.net/7hL0x3m5/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer stated above is all good unless the text in second `<td>` element increases.I have found a better solution which does work in my case.
Instead of putting the value of `#output` in another `<td>` i can inline that in the previous `<td>` and that way the space won't be there. Here's how

`Code`

```js
var str1 = "78896541230";
str1 = str1.replace(/.(?=.{4})/g, 'x');
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = str1;
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" class="formtable">

  <caption>Just for fun</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>The following will contain masked input number <strong id="output"></strong></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> If it is not masked number, then something is wrong.</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" class="formtable">
    <tr>
      <td>The following will contain masked input number </td>
      <td id="output">XXXXXXX0230</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"> If it is not masked number, then something is wrong.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The white space between the text and the 'output' number is being caused by the longer text in the second row. This causes the first column of the first row stretch. You're also nesting `<tr>` elements which you shouldn't.

You could add a `colspan="2"` to the `<td>` in the second row.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.It does work but if I add some more data in first ```<td>``` then the problem still persists.

Comment: @Saurav I'd probably opt for another layout with Flexbox or just regular block elements. I see no need for a table in this setup.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Please check out my answer as it worked for me.

Comment: @Saurav I guess that works too, but why use tables at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cell spacing and cell padding attribute in html 5
And set their values to 0 or -1